# kafka to opentsdb with flink: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, opentsdb

This is my code:

```
def saveToOpenTSDB(rows: Iterator[String], url: String) {
          val requestConfig: RequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(2000).setConnectTimeout(2000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(2000).build()
          val httpClient: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault() }
```

The error stack trace:

> > 2018-10-25 12:40:39,323 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2018-10-25 12:40:39,324 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     -  Starting Command Line Client (Version: 1.6.1, Rev:23e2636, Date:14.09.2018 @ 19:56:46 UTC) 2018-10-25 12:40:39,324 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  OS
> >     current user: root 2018-10-25 12:40:39,676 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - 
> >     Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: root 2018-10-25 12:40:39,676 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  JVM:
> >     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation -
> >     1.8/25.172-b11 2018-10-25 12:40:39,676 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - 
> >     Maximum heap size: 7136 MiBytes 2018-10-25 12:40:39,676 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - 
> >     JAVA_HOME: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_172 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - 
> >     Hadoop version: 2.6.5 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  JVM
> >     Options: 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     -Dlog.file=/root/flink-1.6.1/log/flink-root-client-cuiyk-cdn-test-10.log
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/root/flink-1.6.1/conf/log4j-cli.properties 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/root/flink-1.6.1/conf/logback.xml 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     -  Program Arguments: 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     run 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -     -c
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     -     dataclean.FlinkDataCleanDemo 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     --parallelism 2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -     4
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:39,678 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     -     --jobmanager 2018-10-25 12:40:39,679 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     cuiyk-cdn-test-4:42115 2018-10-25 12:40:39,679 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     ./flinkkafka2tsdb.jar 2018-10-25 12:40:39,679 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - 
> >     Classpath:
> >     /root/flink-1.6.1/lib/flink-python_2.11-1.6.1.jar:/root/flink-1.6.1/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.6.1.jar:/root/flink-1.6.1/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/root/flink-1.6.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/root/flink-1.6.1/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.6.1.jar::/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.3-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.2/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop:
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:39,679 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend 
> >     - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2018-10-25 12:40:39,682 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: classloader.resolve-order,
> >     parent-first 2018-10-25 12:40:39,682 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:39,682 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123 2018-10-25
> >     12:40:39,682 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration 
> >     - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.size, 1024m 2018-10-25 12:40:39,682 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.size, 1024m
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:39,683 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:39,683 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1 2018-10-25
> >     12:40:39,683 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration 
> >     - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8081 2018-10-25 12:40:39,696 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli
> >     - Found Yarn properties file under /tmp/.yarn-properties-root. 2018-10-25 12:40:39,914 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop
> >     user set to root (auth:SIMPLE) 2018-10-25 12:40:39,936 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     Running 'run' command. 2018-10-25 12:40:39,940 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     Building program from JAR file 2018-10-25 12:40:40,314 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      - Rest
> >     client endpoint started. 2018-10-25 12:40:40,316 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -
> >     Starting execution of program 2018-10-25 12:40:40,316 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient        -
> >     Starting program in interactive mode (detached: false) 2018-10-25
> >     12:40:40,346 WARN 
> >     org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09  -
> >     Ignoring configured key DeSerializer (key.deserializer) 2018-10-25
> >     12:40:40,346 WARN 
> >     org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09  -
> >     Ignoring configured value DeSerializer (value.deserializer) 2018-10-25
> >     12:40:40,532 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration 
> >     - Loading configuration property: classloader.resolve-order, parent-first 2018-10-25 12:40:40,532 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:40,532 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123 2018-10-25
> >     12:40:40,532 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration 
> >     - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.size, 1024m 2018-10-25 12:40:40,532 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.size, 1024m
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:40,532 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
> >     2018-10-25 12:40:40,532 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            -
> >     Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1 2018-10-25
> >     12:40:40,533 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration 
> >     - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8081 2018-10-25 12:40:40,540 INFO 
> >     org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient        -
> >     Submitting job 1b45b5780e0e7067fae20be1db8e7c2f (detached: false).
> >     2018-10-25 12:41:38,177 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient
> >     - Shutting down rest endpoint. 2018-10-25 12:41:38,179 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      - Rest
> >     endpoint shutdown complete. 2018-10-25 12:41:38,180 ERROR
> >     org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - Error
> >     while running the command.
> >     org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job
> >     failed. (JobID: 1b45b5780e0e7067fae20be1db8e7c2f)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:267)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:486)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.scala:654)
> >             at dataclean.FlinkDataCleanDemo$.main(FlinkDataCleanDemo.scala:162)
> >             at dataclean.FlinkDataCleanDemo.main(FlinkDataCleanDemo.scala)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:426)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:804)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:280)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:215)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1044)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120)
> >             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >             at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
> >             at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
> >             at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> >     org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
> >             at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:912)
> >             at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
> >             at dataclean.CommonDeploy$.saveToOpenTSDB(CommonDeploy.scala:21)
> >             at dataclean.FlinkDataCleanDemo$$anonfun$main$1.apply(FlinkDataCleanDemo.scala:152)
> >             at dataclean.FlinkDataCleanDemo$$anonfun$main$1.apply(FlinkDataCleanDemo.scala:150)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream$$anon$4.map(DataStream.scala:607)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:579)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:689)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:667)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream$$anon$6$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(DataStream.scala:663)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream$$anon$6$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(DataStream.scala:663)
> >             at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:73)
> >             at scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.foreach(MutableList.scala:30)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream$$anon$6.flatMap(DataStream.scala:663)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFlatMap.processElement(StreamFlatMap.java:50)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:579)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:689)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:667)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:202)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:105)
> >             at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
> >             at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
//related dependecies:
    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this is just what I wanna express!

Comment: I did resolve this problem by that mean.

Comment: @GhostCat Oh, you're right, thanks for this kind commit!

Comment: And you can finally delete no longer required comments...

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem, by adding this in maven shade plugin in ‘configuration’ label, as following:

```
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shade.org.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
```

Comment: Good! You might want to accept the answer when the time allows to do. You could improve the code formatting a bit (you only need 4 spaces to indent code, there is no need to use 15 or 30. That just moves stuff to far to the right). And welcome to upvote privileges!